# Creating structural Navigation in SharePoint 2013 wiki subsite is extremely slow or couldn't create

Tags: sharepoint, navigation, sharepoint-2013, wiki

I have a wiki subsite on my site collection. I can create structural navigation in top level site without any problem, but when I create navigation link in my wiki subsite it started rounding and rounding without any action and page becomes white and after all the navigation link isn't created. I tested everything that came to my mind.
Just for test, I removed all of my pages except Home page in my test environment, then navigation creates fast, but I don't know what's wrong with my pages.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things to look at, you can review this blog post  [Troubleshooting Page Load Issues](http://nextconnect.blogspot.com/2010/01/troubleshooting-page-loading-issues.html) to get started. Also, go to check the ULS logs, maybe you will find some related clues there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check ULS logs

Comment: After I viewed ULS log I found out this error that seems related to my issue:  An unexpected error occurred while manipulating the navigational structure of this Web.

Answer (score 0):

After I viewed ULS log I found out this error that seems related to my issue: An unexpected error occurred while manipulating the navigational structure of this Web.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).